# PHP why is my INNER JOIN returning errors?

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join

I have this line of code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id`, `image`, `link`, `order` FROM `galleryImages` INNER JOIN `galleries` ON `galleryImages`.`galleryId` = `galleries`.`id`");
```

its returning this error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result
```

full code:

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT `id`, `image`, `link`, `order` FROM `galleryImages` INNER JOIN `galleries` ON `galleryImages`.`galleryId` = `galleries`.`id`");
                $results = array();
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                        $results[] = $row;
                }
                return $results;
```

Comment: We dont see any `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` in your code.

Comment: var_dump($query) after the first line to be sure it contains what you think it contains.

Comment: Use mysqli_error($connection) to find out more after you run the query. http://www.php.net/mysqli_error

Comment: `var_dump($query)` returns `bool(false)`;

Comment: if i take out the inner join, it works

Comment: $query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT id, image, link, order FROM galleryImages a JOIN galleries b ON a.galleryId = b.id") or die( mysqli_error($connection)); 

 to see what kind of error it is having.. or w/e the mysqli error function is.

Comment: For future code: You don't need to quote/backtick your column & table names.  They only add visual clutter and are just one more way for you to make syntax errors, or to confuse single quotes and backticks.  The only reason you need them is if you have a name that is a reserved word, or you have embedded spaces or punctuation in them, and those are terrible practices to avoid anyway.

Comment: "if I take out the inner join it works" - LOL! no it doesn't.

Comment: You should be using prepared statements as well. This query doesn't have any paramaeters, but you likely do have some other SQL statement in your code that uses variables from the user, and you likely have SQL injections in your code. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php and http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
"SELECT `id`, `image`, `link`, `order`
  FROM `galleryImages` `g`
  INNER JOIN `galleries` `g2` ON `g`.`galleryId` = `g2`.`id`"
```

Comment: My only nit pick is the removal of the \` around everything, but to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

This should work..

```
SELECT 
    `galleries`.`id`, 
    `galleries`.`image`, 
    `galleries`.`link`, 
    `galleries`.`order` 
FROM 
    `galleryImages` 
    INNER JOIN `galleries` 
        ON `galleryImages`.`galleryId` = `galleries`.`id`
```

Comment: Please do check the table <> fields, It could be the other way round.